# How to connect to Redis (Sentinel)

Tags: go, redis

My code with which I try to connect to REDIS SENTINEL. Since I'm new to golang wanted to clarify what's wrong with me? REDIS SENTINEL is configured and works correctly.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/go-redis/redis"
)

func main() {
    rdb:=redis.NewFailoverClient(&redis.FailoverOptions(
            MasterName: "mymaster",
            SentinelAddrs: "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:26379","XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:26379","XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:26379",
    ))
    rdb.Ping()
}
```

Run:

```
$ go run redis.go
**# command-line-arguments**
>./redif.go:11:12: syntax error: unexpected :, expecting comma or )**
```

Comment: I think it should read `&redis.FailoverOptions{ MasterName: "mymaster", SentinelAddrs: "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:26379","XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:26379","XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:26379", }` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that you have used the wrong formatted string slice.

See the [FailoverOption{}](https://godoc.org/github.com/go-redis/redis#FailoverOptions) from **"go-redis"** pkg. It says the `.SentinelAddrs` is of `[]string` type.

```golang
rdb:=redis.NewFailoverClient(&redis.FailoverOptions(
    MasterName: "mymaster",
    SentinelAddrs: []string{"XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:26379","XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:26379","XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:26379"},
))
```

Comment: @Shurilla That is not the way you thank anyone. If the post is helpful, Stackoverflow has a system to give upvote and accept the answer.